# How to handle application with 3rd party dll reference

Tags: c#, .net, dll

I am writing a c# WinForms application. I reference a 3rd Party dll (SDK) to perform specific tasks. I expect this dll to be installed on clients machine.

Now, if I use say Version 1 as reference , and client has Version 1 installed. The application works.

Later, if the client has upgraded to Version 2, my application wont work because, there is no more Version 1 dll.

How do I code my application? One for each version of the 3rd party dll? or is there a better way? (SDK is backward compatible)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add an assembly binding redirect to app.config.  Something like this:

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="someAssembly"
      publicKeyToken="32ab4ba45e0a69a1"
      culture="en-us" />

    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="7.0.0.0" newVersion="8.0.0.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

See [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7wd6ex19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: +1. If "3rd party SDK" would be expecting it to be used than on upgrade it would specify this policy for machine... Or at least let SDK clients know how to handle new version... Since OP did not get/find such information expecting backward compatibility may be too optimistic...

Comment: Does this handle even if my application is newer than the installed SDK version?

Comment: @billboard - It's not checking your application's version.  It basically saying, any requests to bind to _oldVersion_ of SDK assembly redirect them to _newVersion_ of SDK assembly.  I think as long as the new version is backward compatible, it should work.